# Quantum Field Theory for Economics and Finance

Tags: books, quantum-finance

Amazon suggested me this [book](https://www.amazon.it/Quantum-Field-Theory-Economics-Finance/dp/1108423159) with a very catchy title, especially to the ones, like me, who have a background in physics. Do you think it's worth reading? I haven't found any reviews yet, which makes me wonder what the financial industry/academia actually thinks about B. Baaquie work.

Comment: If your background is in theoretical physics then you might like the earlier books on the subject by the same author -Quantum finance, and Interest rates and coups bonds in quantitative finance. Both have plenty of reviews. This new book seems to dedicate a lot of pages to explaining the basic quantum concepts, probably because the main criticism of the ‘older’ books centred around this theme- written for people with background in theoretical physics!

Comment: I remember Belal Baaquie . He seemed to have some very interesting ideas! If you're searching for a book with reviews, look at https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/0521714788/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely give it a try.